# Change width of a segmented control based on titles in each segment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, width, uisegmentedcontrol

Starts like this, which I like:
[image: Screenshot1.png]

But then I add a segment and this happens:
[image: Screenshot2.png]
The width is set in IB, not in code.

All I need is a method to calculate width on the fly. At the end, it would do something like this:

```
control.width = (labelWidths + marginWidths);
// where marginWidths = (marginWidth * control.numberOfSegments)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method in prgrmr's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6712874/536462) works fine for its intended purpose, but this is not it.

Rather than adding unnecessary overhead with custom UILabel subviews,
I've modified the example code in the above link to come up with this:

```
- (void)resizeSegmentsToFitTitles:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
    CGFloat textWidth = 0; // total width of all text labels
    CGFloat marginWidth = 0; // total width of all margins
    NSUInteger nSegments = control.subviews.count;
    UIView *aSegment = [control.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UIFont *theFont = nil;

    // get font for segment title label
    for (UILabel *label in aSegment.subviews) {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            theFont = label.font;
            break;
        }
    }

    // calculate width of text in each segment
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < nSegments; i++) {
        NSString *title = [control titleForSegmentAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat width = [title sizeWithFont:theFont].width;
        CGFloat margin = 15;

        if (width > 200) {
            NSString *ellipsis = @"…";
            CGFloat width2 = [ellipsis sizeWithFont:theFont].width;

            while (width > 200-width2) {
                title = [title substringToIndex:title.length-1];
                width = [title sizeWithFont:theFont].width;
            }

            title = [title stringByAppendingString:ellipsis];
        }

        [control setTitle:title forSegmentAtIndex:i];

        textWidth += width;
        marginWidth += margin;
    }

    // resize segments to accomodate text size, evenly split total margin width
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < nSegments; i++) {
        // size for label width plus an equal share of the space
        CGFloat textWidth = [[control titleForSegmentAtIndex:i]
                             sizeWithFont:theFont].width;
        // the control leaves a 1 pixel gap between segments if width
        // is not an integer value; roundf() fixes this
        CGFloat segWidth = roundf(textWidth + (marginWidth / nSegments));
        [control setWidth:segWidth forSegmentAtIndex:i];
    }

    // set control width
    [control setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (textWidth + marginWidth), 30)];
}
```

Comment: I am using this in ios7 to correct a problem with the segmented controller truncating the titles when it shouldn't however the last segment is not tapable... any ideea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890428/uisegmentedcontrol-truncates-segment-titles

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23492688/2254935) is simplified and iOS 7 friendly version.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the property`apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent` and set it to`YES`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when I change the text programmatically.

Comment: @primehalo Try setting this property every time after you update the text programmatically.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh for quick Fix!!

Answer (score 12):

As shown in below pic change Auto-Size property to 'Proportional to Content'.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's the quickest, easiest and works great. Thank you, Ankit.

Comment: The text is truncated.. It does not go on the next line

Answer (score 6):

The first option looks like this:

```
segmentedControl.setWidth(100, forSegmentAt: 0)
segmentedControl.setWidth(50, forSegmentAt: 1)
```

That gives you individually sized segments while sticking to a value you define, which means you get to tweak the aesthetics as you want. The second option looks like this:

```
segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```

That hands full control over to iOS, which is probably the best thing to do most of the time.

Available from iOS 5.0

[**hackingwithswift**](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-set-different-widths-for-a-uisegmentedcontrols-elements)

Answer (score 1):

It will adjust the size of the segmented control to accommodate the text in the text labels of each segment.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0
   }
```