# UISegmentedControl, text truncated on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an UISegmentedControl in my app and on iOS 7 text is truncated. Instead of having "Stations" I have "S." even if my control is 320 width.
Using Spark Inspector I am able to see that size of label containing text is very small (13 pixels).
Also it works on iOS 7.1.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Thierry

[image]

EDIT: I created a blank project and it works...

Comment: can you post a sample? Its working here.

Comment: I do nothing special, just drag a UISegmentedControl in any xib I got this strange behaviour. Base SDk is iOS 7 and deployment is iOS 6.1

Comment: Check if you set a width for segment control later in code.

Comment: You can see the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31470431/1920799

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change width of a segmented control based on titles in each segment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990330/change-width-of-a-segmented-control-based-on-titles-in-each-segment)