# How to complete show the text of Segmented Control in iOS?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am developing in iOS. I try to use `Segmented Control`, but the text of `Segmented Control` is too long like the following picture:

[image]

Does there has any method to show all text in `Segmented Control`?

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Lots of help here : [Change width of a segmented control based on titles in each segment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990330/change-width-of-a-segmented-control-based-on-titles-in-each-segment)

Comment: Will  look at it. Thanks

Comment: Consider to use other controls if it's too wide to fit in one line, like picker.

Comment: you need to add the scrollView to give space for horizontally. SO that the Segmented control can display complete text accordingly

Comment: You can use the property apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent and set it toYES

Answer (score 1):

**1st Way :** Change font size to a smaller size which can be accommodated in segment

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes 
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**2nd Way :** set width of segment according to text. (Thanks to the_UB for comment)

Please refer [How can I calculate correct widths for UISegmentedControl segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688485/how-can-i-calculate-correct-widths-for-uisegmentedcontrol-segments/6712874#6712874)

**3rd Way :** Try to use scrollable control like segments

Please refer : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/carbonkit and https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagingmenucontroller

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would help others

You can set the width to each item of Segment Control like this

```
segmentedControl.setWidth(100, forSegmentAt: 0)
segmentedControl.setWidth(50, forSegmentAt: 1)
```

or this way

```
segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```